# check a condition before a ajax call back of form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-ajax

I have written ajax callback on a textfield and it is called on blur event.

But before It going for ajax callback I want to check a condition that textfield not empty.

So I want,If textfield is not empty then the ajax callback is get called otherwise it should not get called.

Thanks in advance

form_example is my module name

**Form control**

```
$form['price_form']['item'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Item Name?',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 25,
    '#id' => 'nameId',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
        // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
        // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element changes.
        'callback' => 'form_example_simplest_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'listDiv',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'examples/form_example/item_name_autocomplete_callback',
);
```

**JS Code**

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Hi, Javascript successfully attached');

        Drupal.behaviors.form_example = {
            attach: function (context, settings) {

                // Overwrite beforeSubmit
                Drupal.ajax['nameId'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
                    alert('dsf');
                }
            }
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I am printing alert for testing.I tried by its name and by its id but not getting alert.I got below alert so js inclusion fine.

```
alert('Hi, Javascript successfully attached');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ajax implementation in the form api lets you specify a 'beforeSubmit' handler that will be run before submission. According to this : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object if that function returns false the form won't be submitted.

You should be able to add a beforesubmit handler something like:

```
Drupal.behaviors.MyModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    // Overwrite beforeSubmit
    Drupal.ajax['your_element'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
        // check the textfield isn't blank then return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: ,Thank you for response I edited question according to you but still not getting a simple alert.

Comment: You might want to check what the elements are called in the Drupal.ajax object - if you are in chrome dev tools try doing console.log(Drupal.ajax), it might actually look something like 'edit-price_form-item'

Comment: Giving error in console,"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"

Comment: Not sure what I can tell you other than that seems like the error you would get if you didn't have the right ID in the Drupal.ajax[ID] part. Without looking over your shoulder I can't tell you what that should be, but it's the ID of your form element.

Comment: Oh great Thank you man,I was considering it as JQuery selector that’s why attaching extra '#' to it.Now It is working and thank you again